# How can i get cakephp current model's foreign key column name?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Is there way to get current model's foreign key name in other model something like this

```
echo $this->Category->whatIsMyForeignKeyName();
// expected output 'category_id'
```

Edit: Version

```
strtolower($this->Category->alias).'_id'
```

somehow seems not in spirit of cake.

Comment: ...Why do you need the foreign key of the database?

Comment: Not database, currently used model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did with strtolower will work in almost all (or maybe all?) cases, though a slightly more thorough way would be something like:

```
$fkey = Inflector::singularize(Inflector::tableize($this->Category->alias)).'_id';
```

But the question I'd be asking is why do you want to do that? Why not just hard-code it as 'category_id'?

Comment: Because it is used in behavior and model can be Category, Document or anything else. And I need to check whether I can build associations with another dynamically assigned model.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also not a generic solution. Consider a model called `Task` which has multiple `BelongsTo` associations on `User` model, say owner and assignee. What if the developer used columns called `owner` and `assignee` in DB and no column called `user_id`?

Comment: This still doesn't look right. I'm looking for a more flexible option for exactly the reason @Fr0zenFyr pointed out. The project's database naming (tables and columns) is messy and I'd like to rename all that to meet the conventions somewhere later, and I need the code to adjust itself automatically by me editing the models configurations only without having to go through the rest of the code.

Answer (score 5):

If you know what kind of relation it is (belongsTo for example), you can easily look it up in the defined relations:

```
$foreignKey = $this->belongsTo['Category']['foreignKey'];
```

Comment: That is not possible if model does not have any associations at the time

Comment: When do you bind the associations? Of course you can only look it up after you completed the binding (or use non dynamic $belongTo defintion).

Comment: Associations are bound in behavior's setup() method with dynamically selected model

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it in another way.

joshua.paling's solution finds you the *default* foreign key. Anyway, I think you can find it a step easier:

`Inflector::underscore($baseModelName).'_id';`

But as a matter of fact a model may have different foreign keys for each associations. Let's assume there is a "Base" and it has many "Associated" (these are dummy names for models). The relations is "hasMany" relation.

So your definition of "Base" model is the following:

```
class Base extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany = array(
    'Associated'
  );
}
```

In the "BaseController" you can retrieve the foreign key that links these models together in the following way:

`$this->Base->hasMany['Associated']['foreignKey']`

This is the foreign key used for linking "Associated" rows to the relating "Base" row in the database.

I know this question is already answered more then a year ago but I hope my answer could help some other people :)

Comment: But I don't have neither $hasMany, nor any other association at the time... I want(ed) to bind them dynamically in behavior. (As I try remember the problem :) )